# Nested if statements inside case_when

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to mutate a large data set, and am wondering if there is a better way to run this code:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(id = c('person 1', 'person 2'), a1 = c(0, 1), a2 = c(1, 0), a3 = c(0, 0), b1 = c(0, 1), b3 = c(1, 0))

new_function = function(name){
    df %>% mutate(
    !!name := case_when( 
    if(any(names(df) == paste0(name,'_1'))){ !!sym(paste0(name,'1')) == 1 ~ 1 },
    if(any(names(df) == paste0(name,'_2'))){ !!sym(paste0(name,'2')) == 1 ~ 2 },
    if(any(names(df) == paste0(name,'_3'))){ !!sym(paste0(name,'3')) == 1 ~ 3 },
    TRUE ~ 0)
    )
}

col_names = c('a', 'b')

col_names %>%
    map(new_function)
```

To add two new columns:

```
a = c(2,1)
b = c(3,1)
```

The problem is the vector col_names has over a hundred entries and I'm not sure which columns are missing.  It seems very inefficient to scan the entire data frame for each column name in each statement of case_when.

I tried to use possibly() or safely() (without the if statements) to ignore the error and keep running through the code, but it gave the same error as before.

*Note each person can only have one '1' for each letter, so only one statement of case_when can evaluate to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Since, we know that each person can have only one 1 in each `col_names`, we can use that fact to simplify our logic. We can select column which starts with `col_names` get the column number which has 1 in it using `max.col` and return the value from the column name by removing all the non-numeric data from it.

```
library(dplyr)

new_function <- function(x) {
  temp <- df %>% select(starts_with(x))
   as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", names(temp)[max.col(temp)]))
}

bind_cols(df, purrr::map_dfc(col_names, new_function))

#        id a1 a2 a3 b1 b3 V1 V2
#1 person 1  0  1  0  0  1  2  3
#2 person 2  1  0  0  1  0  1  1
```